# How to increase a variable in a .jsp page when the page is refreshed

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

In my Liferay portlet view.jsp page I have `int i =0;` (I know that it is not good to have java code in jsp pages but I have to) now I need to increase it whenever the page is refreshed. I added  `<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="4">` to refresh the page.

Comment: You could create a static variable if it is increased across all users if not then you could store the variable in a cookie...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
<%! int i =1; %>
<%
    System.out.println(i++);
%>
```

But as you yourself said it is not recommended to use java code in .jsp pages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be an option to store this variable in portlet session scope and increment on page request.

Answer (score 0):

U have to intialize count in session object for that u have to 
set it in session object using setattribute function before this page
and in the page where u want to check it use the following code

```
 <%
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null){
         Integer Count= 
              (Integer)session.getAttribute("Count");




            if( Count==null || Count== 0 ){
               /* First visit */
               out.println("Welcome to my website!");
               Count=count+ 1;
            }else{
Count=count+ 1;
  out.println("Welcome back again for the "+Count+"Time");
}
            session.setAttribute("Count", Count);
        %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the variable static

```
<% static int i = 0; %>
```